# Let $f$ be nonconstant analytic in a domain $D$ and continuous on its closure. If $|f|$ is constant on $\partial D$, then $f$ has a zero in $D$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, maximum-principle

This exercise has no assumption on the boundedness of $D$, hence $\bar{D}$ is not guaranteed to be compact. Would this be essential for the assertion to be true?

Suppose the nonconstant function $f(z)$ is analytic in a domain $D$ and continuous on its closure. If $|f(z)|$ is constant on the boundary of $D$, prove that $f(z)$ has a zero in $D$.

The obvious approach is to assume by contradiction that $f$ has no zero in $D$. Then we can define a nonconstant analytic function $1/f$ in $D$, which gives us by the Maximum Modulus Theorem that $1/|f|$ does not attain a maximum in $D$. But how can I use this to reach a contradiction?
I am stuck here and I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: @MyGlasses Is the assertion false if $D$ is not bounded?

Comment: As far as I know the boundedness of $D$ is necessary for applying  Maximum Modulus Theorem.

Comment: Both $|f|$ and ${1 \over |f|}$ attain their $\max$ on the boundary, hence $f$ is a constant. So $f$ must have a zero in the interior.

Comment: I think this proposition is not true in general. If $D=\{z\in\mathbf C;|z|>1\},$ and define for each $z\in D$ that $f(z)=1/z$, then $|f(z)|=1$ on $\partial D=\{z\in\mathbf C;|z|=1\}$, and $f$ is analytic in $D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounded case is the application of the maximum modulus principle mentioned in the comments, or in previous questions of this type. The assertion is untrue for unbounded $D$. If $D$ is the half plane and $f(z)=e^{iz}$, then $|f|$ is constant on $\partial D=\mathbb R$ but $f$ has no zeroes in $D$.